# Aligning Views Within a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper that flips between 2 views, one view is an ImageView and one is a TextView.
The size of the image and text varies depending on what I retrieve from the server.

I would like the TextView to always have the same height dimensions as the ImageView so that when the ImageView is flipped the size of the TextView layout does not change, even if there is very little text associated with the TextView; if there is a lot of text I want to do an ellipsize="end" if the height of the TextView exceeds the ImageView.

Below is the code that I am using in my layout:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipperZoneMediumLeft"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgZonePic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/stock_service1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtZoneNameFlipperLeft"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is a description"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

I feel like there is a simple solution to this problem but I am struggling on this way too long. Any help to solve my problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `ImageView` and the `TextView` in a `LinearLayout`, so you can applay weights to them. Set the height of both of them to 0dp and give them each a layout_weight of 1. With this they will always have the same height. Like this:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipperZoneMediumLeft"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgZonePic"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/stock_service1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtZoneNameFlipperLeft"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This is a description"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: You need to wrap each view in it's own `LinearLayout` otherwise you just end up with a single child `ViewFlipper` with the `ImageView` and `TextView` having equal heights in that only `LinearLayout`.

Comment: This unfortunately did not solve my problem, doesn't the viewflipper need to have two child view to function properly using the layout above just put my textview below the imageview